# Query random with Laravel and exclude a specific row

Tags: php, laravel-5

How can I create a query random with laravel and exclude a specific row

I tried this :

```
return $this->user
            ->get()
            ->random(1)
            ->where('id', '!=', 1);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're where needs to be first.

```
return $this->movie::where('id', '!=', 1)
            ->get()
            ->random(1);
```